# Value is not populated in <p:inputMask> in jsf

Tags: jsf, primefaces

when i put attribut mask="" in p:inputMask tag,it populate value properly like this::

```
<h:outputLabel for="lblPostalCode" value="#{label.postalCode}:" style="font-weight:bold" />
<p:inputMask id="lblPostalCode" style="width: 80px" value="#{certHolderDetail.selectAdd.postalCode}" mask="" />
```

But when i used default mask for that field like mask="99999-9999" like this

```
<h:outputLabel for="lblPostalCode" value="#{label.postalCode}:" style="font-weight:bold" />
<p:inputMask id="lblPostalCode" style="width: 80px" value="#{certHolderDetail.selectAdd.postalCode}" mask="99999-9999" />
```

it does not populate the value......:(
Please look this.

Comment: What do you mean `it does not populate the value`?  Do you meant that you are unable to type into the inputMask?  The mask does not work as expected?  The backing bean value is not being updated on postback?  See the showcase example for inputMask for an example of how this component should be used: `http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/inputMask.jsf`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My guess would be that the value (#{certHolderDetail.selectAdd.postalCode}) does not actually conform to the pattern. Eg, perhaps it is a 5 digit address, instead of the expected 5+4?